# Limit of correlation for random walks

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I want to show that
\begin{align}
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1/\pi\sqrt{mk}-1/\pi\sqrt{m(m+k)}}{[1/\sqrt{\pi m}-1/\pi m]^{1/2}[1/\sqrt{\pi(m+k)}-1/\pi(m+k)]^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi k}}
\end{align}

This is from p. 9 of the following probability lectures notes http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~conlon/math625/chapter1.pdf, and I'm stuck trying to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Just multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{m}$ (giving $\sqrt[4]{m}$ to each factor on the bottom.) From there the limit can be taken termwise and the answer drops right out.

Comment: That was helpful.  Is there anything in particular that allowed you to notice that?

Comment: @mlstudent The $1/\sqrt{m}$ decay of the first term on the top is slower than the second term, so if you multiply them by $\sqrt{m}$ you get a constant term plus something that goes away. Then it's just a matter of seeing if that $\sqrt{m}$ makes the bottom go to a constant as well (and it helps that the factors on the bottom are very similar in limit behavior in $m$ as the one on the top).